# How to protect and authenticate an entire web folder with Azure and IIS

Tags: php, windows, azure, iis

I am trying to figure out if there are other or better ways of authenticating in Microsoft Azure than my current solution.

I do have a PHP application that is setup in Windows Server 2019 and IIS. I am using the [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) library which works okay - it will authenticate in Azure with no problems.

But... it authenticates on a **file-by-file** basis meaning that I need to include the Azure authentication in each PHP file where I want it to authenticate. Something like this is working fine:

https://whatever.local/secure/myfile.php:

```
# ----------
# myfile.php
# ----------

# Include the SimpleSAMLphp library
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/../simpleSAMLphp/lib/_autoload.php");

# Make sure I am authenticated in Azure
$azure = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple("my-identity");
$azure->requireAuth();

# Get Azure data
$azureUserAttr = $azure->getAttributes();

# Get the data in to useable variables
$azureId = $azureUserAttr["userid"][0] ?? "";
$azureEmail = $azureUserAttr["email"][0] ?? "";

# Print the variables
echo "ID=$azureId<br />";
echo "Email=$azureEmail<br />";
```

Would it be possible instead to install some kind of Windows IIS runtime that would protect the entire **folder**, so every time I call something in e.g. `/secure/` then it authenticates with Azure?

For example - how to ensure that I must be authenticated in Azure before I can fetch this imaginary picture, https://whatever.local/secure/picture.jpg ? Can I protect the entire `/secure/` folder?

Ideally it could do that and then I should have the Azure attributes/claims available as server variables in PHP?

Comment: Since PHP application can be executed under IIS intergrated pipeline. HTTP module could be used to verify authentication token based on url with /secure/. You can use httpmodule to check specific cookie. If there's no such cookie, you can redirect it to authenticate page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A long time has passed but the other day I stumpled upon the exact solution for my problem - [Shibboleth Service Provider](https://www.shibboleth.net/products/service-provider/). This will do exactly what I wanted - protect my IIS web server on folder level and authenticate through Azure if required - AND it will provide the data in web server-side variables.

The Shibboleth SP is a native Windows application that is installed and it provides a Windows service and integrates in to IIS as a module. Do make sure to enable the `Configure IIS Module` in the installation. It is even quite easy to setup. Of course this is different for everyone but in my case I just needed to change a few parameters in two files:

**shibboleth2.xml**

```
<InProcess>
    <ISAPI normalizeRequest="true" safeHeaderNames="true">
        <Site id="YOUR.IIS.SITE.ID" name="YOUR.WEB.FQDN"/>
    </ISAPI>
</InProcess>
<!-- You get the site ID from IIS Manager -->

<!-- Below I make sure the /secure folder is proper secured with Azure -->
<!-- More folders could be added if required -->
<RequestMapper type="Native">
    <RequestMap>
    <Host name="YOUR.WEB.FQDN">
        <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
    </Host>
    </RequestMap>
</RequestMapper>

<ApplicationDefaults entityID="YOUR.AZURE.ENTITYID"

<SSO entityID="https://sts.windows.net/YOUR.IDENTITY.PROVIDER/">
    SAML2
</SSO>

<!-- Your XML federation data - here I have it as a local file -->
<MetadataProvider type="XML" validate="true" path="metadata.xml"/>
```

**attribute-map.xml**

```
<Attribute name="YOUR.AZURE.ATTRIBUTE.NAME" id="YOUR.SERVER:VARIABLE.NAME"/>
```

You must also configure the **Reply URL** in Azure which per default will be https://YOUR.WEB.FQDN/Shibboleth.sso/SAML2/POST

When configured (and after every configuration change) then you need to restart the IIS and Shibboleth service, `Shibboleth Daemon (Default)`.

After Shibboleth configuration then you can check https://YOUR.WEB.FQDN/Shibboleth.sso/Status and see if it gives an XML output (it must). You should however change the IP address in `shibboleth2.xml` to be your local computer from where you do the web request:

```
<Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="YOUR.COMPUTER.IP ::1"/>
```

The logout URL will be https://YOUR.WEB.FQDN/Shibboleth.sso/Logout

At logout you can also redirect to another URL, instead of the one configured in Azure, by adding a `return` parameter - e.g. https://YOUR.WEB.FQDN/Shibboleth.sso/Logout?return=/MyReturnDir/

Once done then you suddenly have all the Azure variables as web server-side variables. In the below example I have some attributes defined in Azure and I need to map that in `attribute-map.xml`:

```
<Attribute name="ADCompanyName" id="Company"/>
<Attribute name="ADUserFirstName" id="FirstName"/>
<Attribute name="ADUserLastName" id="LastName"/>
```

Then from PHP I can get this server-side variable, `$_SERVER["Company"]` with the content of the logged in Azure user.